# Where is town Mieljkow in early 20th century Russia?

Tags: immigration, russia, historical-gazetteer, 1900s-decade

My ancestors came through Ellis Island in 1904. The last place of residence is listed as Mieljkow. We know it is in Russia.

Does anyone know where it is?

---

Only 1 Ellis Island arrival index uses Mieljkow

SHIP NAME Kroonland
ARRIVAL DATE March 15th, 1904
Port of Departure Antwerp
Seidenknopf family, lines 4-7

Ellis Island indexing
Seidenkeropf, Frthe  Mieljkow    45
Seidenkeropf, Gerson     Mieljkow    15
Seidenkeropf, Scheine    Mieljkow    7
Seidenkeropf, Sore Gittel    Mieljkow    16

Ancestry indexing
[Fethe Scidenknoff](http://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?indiv=try&db=nypl&h=4003300110)  abt 1859
Tore Gillel Scidenknoff abt 1888    Hebrew
Gerson Scidenknoff  abt 1889    Hebrew
Tchaina Scidenknoff abt 1897    Hebrew

[image: passenger list cropped to placename]

[image: NYT715_437-0160]

Comment: Hi Scatz, welcome to Genealogy & Family History SE! Are you able to include an image of the handwriting? I'm not saying you're reading it incorrectly but given a Google for "Mieljkow" brings up no results, it would be helpful to see the primary source. You can edit your post and add an image using the [edit] button right below your question. Thanks!

Comment: It might be listed in the US documents as Mieljkov, but transliterated incorrectly. In that case we can only guess what the original name was.

Comment: The clerks who created the passenger lists were employees of the steamship companies, working from forms that were filled out at the time the tickets were purchased, presumably by the person who bought the ticket or someone in their party. Thus they had the same difficulties reading the handwriting on the individual forms as any of us, plus tehy were working with a smaller sample of each person's handwriting than a modern indexer does.

Answer (score 4):

Best guess: Milejkava (Мілэйкава), Belarus -- which was also known as Mileykovo, Grodno Gubernia (province), Russian Empire.

Russian town names that end in *-kovo* were sometimes written as *-kow*, and this town is not far from the modern-day Polish border where they would use *-kow*.

There's a Belarusian page in Wikipedia for the town, but little other English language material that I could find:
https://be.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%91%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9C%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8D%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0

Also, the proper surname is likely Seidenkopf, and the person they're going to looks like Hilel Seidenkopf, their husband/father.   If you can find his immigration papers or naturalization papers or World War I draft card, that can help you confirm the town or region name.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a different place, but there is a Melnikov about 120 km east of Rostov... (such a place might be translated as 'Milltown' so it could be very generic -- again assuming it is Mel(n)ikov)